# How to create an index so that the following statement has an index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have table A(id,name,code)

I have sql statement:

```
Select * from A where upper(code || name) like upper('%<search text>%');
```

How to create an index so that the following statement has an index?
Question for two option: table partitioned, and table not partitioned

Thanks & BR

Comment: You could create a function based index but the LIKE means that it may not use the index anyway. There are also guidelines for asking questions; https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: not answer, function based index can't  use with like '%%' . Thanks!!!

Comment: An index stores your data alphabetically or sequentially - why would you expect oracle to use the index if you are searching LIKE '%TEXT'?  However, it will work for LIKE 'TEXT%'

Comment: Can you change the predicate to use something like `CONTAINS` (which could use an Oracle Text index), or must the predicate be in that exact format?

Comment: I know about Oracle Text Index (CONTEXT - CONTAINS, CTXCAT - CATSEARCH)
But I can not determine whether to create indexes by code (code || name)
I would like to ask if it is possible to create index ((code || name))?
And the performance when insert, update the table will be?
Does the size of the physical storage database file increase?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a performance issue or is this just a hypothetical question?

An index is unlikely to help with this example: a full table scan will probably be the quickest solution.  Why?  Your table has 3 columns.  The best index would be one that avoided looking in the table at all e.g.

```
create index ai on a (code, name, id);
```

But that needs to contain all the same data as the table plus a ROWID for each table row - so it is going to be **bigger** than the table and take longer to scan.  You could try putting the columns in the index with the least selective first and using compression:

```
create index ai on a (code, name, id) compress;
```

Now the index **may** be smaller than the table - it depends on how selective the code and name columns are.  If it is small enough, the optimizer might decide to use it instead of the table.  It still contains all the IDs and ROWIDs  so the reduction in size probably won't be dramatic.  In the test case I set up the compressed index is about half the size of the table, yet Explain Plan shows the query has a higher cost if I use a hint to force it to use the index - maybe due to overheads of compression, I don't know.

You could look into Oracle Text and the `CONTAINS` expression - but then you would be writing a different query, not using `LIKE`.

Comment: I had intended to use the context index but I wanted the result of the query to be the result of the above statement. Select * from A where upper(code || name) like upper('%<search text>%');